# Problem instantiating a package with subtype access to variant record

Tags: generics, ada

I try to compile an Ada 95 program with an Ada 2012 compiler. However there are problems with instantiation of the generic package `Garbage_Collector`. The subtype `A_Term` is not accepted in the package instantiation:

```
prolog.adb:27:15: designated type of actual does not match that of formal "Link"
prolog.adb:27:15: instantiation abandoned
```

I have tried to change `A_Term` to `type A_Term is access A_Node;`. Then the package will instantiate, but the rest of the code breaks. Has something changed since Ada 95 and how can I make it work in Ada 2012?

```
procedure Prolog is

   generic
      type Item is limited private;
      type Link is access Item;
   package Garbage_Collector is
      procedure Get (L : in out Link) is null;
   end Garbage_Collector;

   type Node_Tag is (A, B);

   type Node (Tag : Node_Tag);
   type Term is access Node;

   type Node (Tag : Node_Tag) is
      record
         case Tag is
            when A => null;
            when B => null;
         end case;
      end record;

   subtype A_Node is Node (A);
   subtype A_Term is Term (A);
   package Gc_A is new Garbage_Collector
     (Item => A_Node,
      Link => A_Term);

   T : Term;
begin
   Gc_A.Get (T);
end Prolog;
```

The code is from a Prolog module from Stanford University. [The project on GitHub](https://github.com/jquorning/Prolog)

Comment: Something could have been changed along with [the changes described in this Ada 2005 rationale](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-3-5.html), though I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: A bug with _access subtypes_ could easily have been introduced when they changed the rules for generic formal
access-to-subprogram types, discussed in this [AI](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai05s/ai05-0288-1.txt?rev=1.3&raw=N)

Answer (score 5):

I can't say what exactly causes your error. It could well be that this is a compiler bug. To fix this in a minimal invasive way, I suggest to make the `access` relation invisible to the generic unit:

```vhdl
procedure Prolog is

   generic
      type Item is limited private;
      type Link is private;
      with function Deref (L : Link) return Item is <>;
   package Garbage_Collector is
      procedure Get (L : in out Link) is null;
   end Garbage_Collector;

   type Node_Tag is (A, B);

   type Node (Tag : Node_Tag);
   type Term is access Node;

   type Node (Tag : Node_Tag) is
      record
         case Tag is
            when A => null;
            when B => null;
         end case;
      end record;

   subtype A_Node is Node (A);
   subtype A_Term is Term (A);
   
   function Deref (L : A_Term) return A_Node is (L.all);
   
   package Gc_A is new Garbage_Collector
     (Item  => A_Node,
      Link  => A_Term);

   T : Term;
begin
   Gc_A.Get (T);
end Prolog;
```

Now the compiler does not complain because the formal type `Link` is not an access type anymore and has no relation to `Item`. By giving the function `Deref`, you are still able to dereference an object of type `Link`. You will need an additional function if you need to assign to it.

Answer (score 3):

In your code sample above, you declare types `Node` and `Term`:

```
type Node (Tag : Node_Tag);
type Term is access Node;
```

You then attempt to declare two subtypes:

```
subtype A_Node is Node (A);
subtype A_Term is Term (A);
```

The declaration of `subtype A_Node` makes sense, since `Node` is a discriminant type. The declaration of `subtype A_Term` does not make sense. Type `Term` is `access Node`, which is different from type `Node`. Try changing the declaration of `subtype A_Term` to:

```
subtype A_Term is access A_Node;
```

Comment: The declaration of `A_Term` certainly makes sense, the RM calls it  an _access subtype_. Check [3.10](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-10.html#p23), including the example near the bottom of the page

Comment: The access type has no determinant. Only the accessed type has a determinant. Furthermore, an access to the base type will function as an access to the subtype of that base type.

Comment: It's a discriminant constraint, and is perfectly legal Ada, and I already linked to the RM... The question is not about the legality of the subtype (which is proven legal), it is about the generic formals.